# If you go to the next page "success" else Restart iis

Tags: powershell, iis

Please Help 
I have a website 
I have a problem stopping iis sometimes
Please help with this code
Condition does not work
I want to do this

If you go to the next page
success
else 
Restart iis

```
$url = "https://alatheirvas.com:8443/Login.aspx" 
$username="hgeyf4125" 
$password="123456" 
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application; 
$ie.visible = $true; 
$ie.navigate($url); 
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) 
{ 
Start-Sleep 1; 
} 
$ie.Document.getElementById("Login2_UserName").value = $username 
$ie.Document.getElementByID("Login2_Password").value=$password 
$ie.Document.getElementById("Login2_LoginButton").Click();
while($ie.busy) {sleep 1}
```

The previous steps are correct

What is the next step to accomplish this

If logged in and  go to the next page
success

else 
Restart iis

```
if ($url = "https://alatheirvas.com:8443/agent/") {
"success"
} else {
iisreset 
}
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------------

I want to accomplish this in any way possible

### ---------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: You go to a http:// site and give login credentials? Are you sure that it should not be http**s**://?

Comment: *Is there a better way?* Probably. Calling `Invoke-WebRequest` with appropriate HTTP headers springs to mind. It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: thank you sir
What I'm trying to do
Is to login to the site
If it is successful, Shi does not work
If not successfully completed
Works reboot iis

Page Type - https
I want to achieve this in any way possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to solve this, is using **Invoke-WebRequest**. You can

```
$web=Invoke-WebRequest https://servicios.at.uy/ -SessionVariable sessionWeb
$Form = $web.Forms[0] #Notes below this code block
$Form.Fields["Login2_UserName"]="hgeyf4125"
$Form.Fields["Login2_Password"]="123456"
$status = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ("https://servicios.at.uy/" + $Form.Action) -WebSession $sessionWeb -Method POST -Body $Form.Fields
if ($status.StatusDescription -ge "OK") {
    Write-host "Success"
} else {
    iisreset
}
```

The previous code block checks the status after the login process and, if that is "OK", then it is fine. Otherwise, restart IIS.

**Notes:**
To validate the forms[0] corresponds to the correct form in your Website, you may to run the following:

```
$web = Invoke-WebRequest https://servicios.at.uy/
$Form = $web.Forms[0]
$Form.fields
```

In the column Key will be appear the name of the elements for login ("Login2_UserName" and "Login2_Password").